# http.get() passing ID

Tags: angular, typescript, http-get

I'm trying to get detail info from an URL calling via http.get() in typescript. My URL Endpoint to retrieve this details is a kind of `localhost:8001\character\1234567890` where number is the ID of a character.

If I test on browser, the URL returns correctly all the data.

My issue is on the typescript function call. Fron HTML front, I'm calling function as:

```
<a href="#{{character.id}}" (click)="characterDetail(character.id)">Read more</a>
```

Then, the rest of the functions are these:

```
characterDetail(characterId: number) {
    this.asyncCharDetail = this.getCharacterDetail(characterId)
        .do(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .map(res => res.results);
}



getCharacterDetail(characterId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId,{})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}
```

The `console.log(res)` from first function does not print anything. `characterId` and url are correct both but don't know the reason for not retrieve character details.

The second part when data retrieval is show it on a modal window.

Edit: Here you've got more of the code:

```
private characterDetailApiUrl = 'http://localhost:8001/character/';
....
//To save the character details from Http get.
asyncCharDetail: Observable<string[]>;

characterDetail(characterId: number) {
    console.log('Character detail for ID ' + characterId);
    this.loading = true;
    this.asyncCharDetail = this.getCharacterDetail(characterId)
        .do(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.loading = false;
        })
        .map(res => res.results);
    console.log(this.asyncCharDetail);
}

getCharacterDetail(characterId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId )
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

On Html front file:

```
<a href="" (click)="characterDetail(character.id); $event.preventDefault()">Read more</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the Observable in order for it to do something.

```
characterDetail(characterId: number) {
    this.getCharacterDetail(characterId)
        .do(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .map(res => res.results)
        .subscribe(data => { 
           //...do something with data
        });

}
```

Comment: Mmmm, I've defined `asyncCharDetail: Observable<string[]>;`

Answer (score 0):

`return this.http.get(this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId,{})`

Just the URL should be fine. Can you please check what do you get after you delete `,{}` ? so `return this.http.get(this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId)`

If you need the full response try replacing `{}` with `{ observe: 'response' }`

Comment: If deletion of `{}` same result... Will edit code for give more info abour the issue

Answer (score 0):

I've changed from 2 to 1 function and now I've got some data from the character. Now working as @CornelC suggestion

```
getCharacterDetail(characterId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId)
        .subscribe(res =>
            console.log(res.json())
        );
}
```

Now I'm calling the function from frontend but need to show a modal window with retrieved data

Comment: You get the data because you subscribed (as I suggested), not because you changed from 2 methods to 1